# What is this symbol? `\eth`

Tags: notation

I was reading a LateX document about different symbols and found one called  `\eth`: $\eth$.

Or very similar  `\dh`

It's supposed to be a mathematical symbol, what does it mean?
It looks like a partial derivative but with a strike on it.

Comment: Is a [letter of the alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eth) that fell out of use in the transitional period between Middle and Modern English.  It's still used in Icelandic, though.

Comment: Yes, but what does it mean in mathematics?
$\pi$ is a greek letter but also the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter, the number 3.1415...

Comment: What makes you think that it's used in mathematics?

Comment: Not sure, just asking, but it appears on a Latex list of symbols near other such as derivatives and integrals.

Comment: $\pi$ might also mean a projection, depending on the context. Symbols and concepts are not in one to one correspondence.

Comment: @skan If you clicked Bye_World's link you would have read the following line: "The letter $\eth$ is sometimes used in mathematics and engineering textbooks as a symbol for a spin-weighted partial derivative. This operator gives rise to spin-weighted spherical harmonics."

Comment: Just a pointer: using mathjax on this site, you need only have written `$\eth $` to get $\eth$, or enlarged,  `$\Huge \eth $` to get $\Huge \eth$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special, it is just a symbol. You can even *define* it as a natural number if you want. A symbol itself means nothing deep in mathematics.

As @Bye_World pointed out, people sometimes uses it to denote a differential operator, as the linked Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-weighted_spherical_harmonics#Eth) shows.